# Lightning Dual Listbox style

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, html, lightning-duallistbox

With this code and as you see in the image, I have a mismatch between the box that contains my list and the Selected one, how can I fix this?

I want also to add some space between the list box and the popup bar , is it possible ?

[image]

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="   Form ">
        <lightning-dual-listbox name="getSales"
                                label="  Select Sales "
                                values={sales} 
                                selected-label="Selected"
                                field-level-help="Select your sales "
                                options={sales}
                                ></lightning-dual-listbox>
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="slds-modal__footer">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" aria-label="Cancel and close"> Cancel </button>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Save</button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed  `selected-label="Selected"` and the box was aligned correctly .